# Observer or plugin use before the invoice creation

Tags: magento2, event-observer, invoice, before-plugin

I have create custom attribute("current_seller_id") in `sales_invoice_item` and now want to save some value in this column how can i do this.
Actually i already save the value in `sale_order_item` table with same name attribute("current_seller_id"). i was use around plugin for that. code is

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModuleName\Plugin;
class QuoteToOrder
{
    public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        /** @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);
        $orderItem->setCurrentSellerId($item->getCurrentSellerId());
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

these lines of code save value in each record of `sale_order_item` table. you see this `$item->getCurrentSellerId()` i make attribute "current_seller_id" in eav_attribute table and save value of current user with each product saving.
I need the same event or plugin that fire before saving invoce items in `sales_invoice_item` table because i need to send some custom value in table column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a plugin after `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item::register()` and copy there the data from the order item to the newly created corresponding invoice item.
This could be the plugin method:

```
public function afterRegister(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item $subject, $result)
{
    $result->setCurrentSellerId($result->getOrderItem()->getCurrentSellerId());
    return $result;
}
```

However you can try to add the `current_seller_id` to the fieldset which is used for a newly created invoice item to copy values from an order item. 
But I heard that this doesn't work in some Magento versions.

For this approach add the following into a fieldset.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_order_item">
            <field name="current_seller_id">
                <aspect name="to_invoice_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
<config>
```

Comment: HelgeB ! after plugin or before ? i want to save value in database.

Comment: after is better, before would probably also work. The saving process is however later. The register method is only called when a new invoice is created and therefore it is the best place for you.

Comment: let me check please :)

Comment: Dear HelgeB! It work perfect i use `afterRegister` plugin. Thank You .

Comment: you have the usual events around the save process which every model has, in this case `sales_order_invoice_save_before` and `sales_order_invoice_save_after`