# Event fire before save invoice in `sales_invoice` table

Tags: magento2, sales-invoice, savedata

I want to save value in `sales_invoice` table of custom attribute ("current_seller_id").
i want to know any event that fire before save the invoice in `sales_invoice` table or use plugin of which method.
.
I already done like this functionality in sales_order table via using event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` 
code is give below .

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getData('order');
    $quote = $observer->getData('quote');
    $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();
    foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem){
        if ($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId() != ""){
            $items[]=$quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId();
        }
    }
    $seller_ids=implode(',',$items);
    $order->setCurrentSellerId($seller_ids);
    return $this;
}
```

Same i want to do with `sales_invoice` table.
Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be in sync with your code you already have implemented in [Observer or plugin use before the invoice creation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266326/observer-or-plugin-use-before-the-invoice-creation) you should use for this also a plugin method after `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::register()`. This is the method wich calls also the `register` method for each item.

So if you create the plugin method after `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::register()` you will have all the current seller IDs of the invoice items and can access them there.

The plugin function could be something like this:

```
public function afterRegister(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $subject, $result)
{
    $items = [];
    foreach ($result->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[]=$item->getCurrentSellerId();
    }
    $seller_ids=implode(',',$items);
    $result->setCurrentSellerId($seller_ids);

    return $result;
}
```

It is almost the same action point as using the `sales_order_invoice_register` event but the recommended way to change data is to use plugins.

Comment: HelgeB ! i try this solution. in this plugin use `$result->getAllItems()`.
Dear i use plugin of this method(`getAllItems()`)  .    
`public function afterGetAllItems(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $subject,$items)`  generate error in the method define line.
Error is   ` Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Codility\VendorOrder\Plugin\Item::beforeRegister(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/codility-magento-market-place/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 121 and exactly 2 expected `

Comment: I don't know hat happens in your code, the error you have posted is about 
the beforeRegister() method in the item not in a afterRegister method for the invoice as proposed in the answer. Also I wouldn't suggest to use `afterGetAllItems()` but `afterRegister` as posted in my answer.

Comment: HelgeB ! it work fine . Thank you Dear. 
Actually i was use `beforeRegister()` plugin . i just use now `afterRegister` it work fine.
in my last question you own say you can use before or after plugin thats why i replace after with before and get error.
I don't why can you explain why we can't use `beforeRegister` plugin ?
Thanks

Comment: In the case of the invoice you need to add your code after register, because the register calls for each items are fired within the invoice register method. Therefore before the invoice register method your items do not have the current seller id. Just look at the code of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::register()` and you will understand why you need the after plugin in this case.

Comment: yes got it ! understand thank you